# python plotting from two different files

Tags: python

I have two files, named "data1.dat" and "data2.dat". I want to take first column of "data1.dat"  as xlabel and third column of "data2.dat" as ylabel and make a plot.
How can I do that?
Help please.

Comment: you should know the structure of both file, open them and then plot it, with matplotlib for example.... if you want precise answer, please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

You can read both files and store the required column data in numpy arrays as follows :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with open('data1.dat','r') as f1:
    x=np.genfromtxt(f1) . # I suppose your data1 file has 1 column
with open('data2.dat','r') as f2:
    y=np.genfromtxt(f2)
    y=y[:,2]  # I only the third column

# plot
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. I think it's due to the difference in the numbers of rows of two files.

Comment: You should know the structure of your file as @Dadep said in his comment above. If the two files have different number of rows but you really want to plot their relation, you can either pad with zeros, extrapolate the vector with les of rows or resample the larger vector. Provide us with more information about your files if you want us to help